# custom form in frontend and using this form customer can get appointment

Tags: magento-2.1

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 10 bytes) in C:\wamp64\www\store\vendor\zendframework\zend-code\src\Scanner\FileScanner.php on line 36

Comment: please edit question with more details..... and add code.....